# how to store the gasprice as integer rather than object?

Tags: web3js, javascript

I am trying to get `a` the gas price in terms of integer.

I tried the following

```
// Get references to the modules (or the module content) that we need
var Web3 = require('web3');
const apiKey ='https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/'+Project_ID_Infura
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(apiKey));

// Get the gas price
a=web3.eth.getGasPrice().then(x => {return Number.parseInt(x)*1.4});

typeof(a)
```

the type of a is an "object" when I expect it to be an integer. Can you please help me understand how to store the gasprice as integer rather than object?

Comment: I think the gas price is BigNumber, you can convert it to string or hex using BigNumber libraries

Comment: js has no integer. it has "number" and the returned value could be bigger than the biggest value in that can stored in "number". and try to use "await" instead of .then

Comment: a is not a big number! as it says false to whether it is a BN! web3.utils.isBN(a) gives false! even if you write web3.utils.isBN(web3.eth.getGasPrice())

Comment: @MajdTL regarding your await comment the outcome is web3.eth.getGasPrice(...).await is not a function

Comment: do console.log(a), i think it is undefinded

Comment: it will look like this "var a= await web3.eth.getGasPrice();" but this works only in async functions https://javascript.info/async-await#await

Comment: @MajdTL "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function" gives this error!

Comment: Yes await works only in async function (js problem) need to create an async function and place the logic inside it and then call it.

Comment: @Majed Thank you for trying to help! but I am finding it difficult to follow you. How to fix this? I am really struggling, do you have a code that works for you that fits my description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As KonyTech sais "web3.eth.getGasPrice() returns a Promise so you must treat it as such. In your example a is the Promise, not the gas price" (so you need to understand what are promises in JS before learning web3js :) )

When you connect to Ethereum you need to use BigNumber most of the time because js cannot handle those big numbers used in Ethereum and Solidity.

this script works for me using nodejs and web3js v1.6.0

create package.json file

```
{
  "name": "testApp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node main.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "web3": "^1.6.0"
  }
}
```

then create this file: main.js

```
// Get references to the modules (or the module content) that we need
var Web3 = require('web3');
const apiKey ='https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/' + <your-key>
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(apiKey));

async function main() {
     const gasPriceAsString = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
     console.log(gasPriceAsString); // "1000000011" in WEI
     console.log(typeof gasPriceAsString); // string

     var BN = web3.utils.BN;
     const gasPriceAsBigNumber = new BN(gasPriceAsString);
     console.log(gasPriceAsBigNumber); // BN { negative: 0, words: [ 60475915, 14 ], length: 2, red: null }
     console.log(typeof gasPriceAsBigNumber); // object
     console.log(gasPriceAsBigNumber.toString()); // "1000000011"

     const MAX_NUMBER_IN_JS = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
     console.log(MAX_NUMBER_IN_JS); // 9007199254740991
     const maxNumberInJsAsBigNumber = new BN(MAX_NUMBER_IN_JS);
     console.log(maxNumberInJsAsBigNumber); // BN { negative: 0, words: [ 67108863, 67108863, 1 ], length: 3, red: null }
     console.log(typeof maxNumberInJsAsBigNumber); // object
     console.log(maxNumberInJsAsBigNumber.toString()); // "9007199254740991"

     //compare to make sure that your big number can be convert to number (the max number in js is greate or equal to your bignumber )
     const isSafeToConvert = maxNumberInJsAsBigNumber.gte(gasPriceAsBigNumber);
     if (isSafeToConvert) {
         const gasPriceAsNormalNumber = gasPriceAsBigNumber.toNumber();
         console.log(gasPriceAsNormalNumber); // 1000000011
         console.log(typeof gasPriceAsNormalNumber) // number
     }
}

// call the function
main();
```

then

> npm install

then

> npm run start

Comment: @Majid you are a genius thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, `web3.eth.getGasPrice()` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) so you must treat it as such. In your example `a` is the Promise, not the gas price.

The cleanest way to achieve this is to await on the Promise. Since it is asynchronous, by awaiting it you automatically get the value returned by the Promise:

```
// Get the gas price
a = await web3.eth.getGasPrice();
```

However, we're not done yet since from the [web3 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#getgasprice), the Promise returns the gas price as a **String**. Sure, you can do `a = Number.parseInt(a)` to get the value as a `number` but this is dangerous.

If the value exceeds the range of safe values to use in JavaScript (here [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)) this will most likely create problems in your applications. For this purpose it's better to use one of the existing BigNumber JS libraries that exist and parse the **String** to a **BigNumber** instead.

Example using **web3.utils**:

```
a = web3.utils.toBN(a)
```

Comment: @KonyTeck Thanks for this as I did what you told me it give me this error "Error: Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number {} to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value."