# Balance - gasPrice = NaN

Tags: web3js, ether

```
    var balance = await web3.eth.getBalance('0xxxx') ;
    var valueToBeSent = balance - gasPrice
    var gasPrice = await web3.eth.getGasPrice() * 21000;

    console.log(balance)
    console.log(gasPrice)
    console.log(valueToBeSent)
```

When I do this, I get the result `NaN` in `valueToBeSent`.

```
Balance=199057199990657509
gasPrice= 1000000008
valueToBeSent=NaN
```

Thanks !

**EDIT :
thanks MAJD TL**

I added:

```
    const BN = require('bn.js');

    var a = new BN(balance);
    var b = new BN(gasPrice);

    var valueToBeSent  = a -= b;
```

Comment: use BigNumbers library maybe it will solve the problem

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but I'm a beginner and don't know how to use BigNumber

Comment: the numbers that come back from solidity ethereum are too big that javascript cannot handel them. so you need to use a library that can understand and work with those big numbers 
web3js support that  check https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.5.2/web3-utils.html#bn

Comment: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/110629/how-to-store-the-gasprice-as-integer-rather-than-object/111395#111395 check here also it show some examples